# Checking the LC245A on board

Tags: integrated-circuit, testing

I want to know how to make sure that the LC245A on the board in the image is not damaged.

[image]

The problem is that some buttons do not work. The short circuit remained when I removed the two pieces in the picture referred to.

Is there an easy way to check it using a multimeter or application circuit?

[image]

Comment: Do you understand what pins 1 and 10 do? It might be the intention that pin 1 is grounded. We have no clue what that circuit is and what it does but the problem might relate to other parts than pins 1 and 10 being shorted.

Comment: pin 10 gnd
pin 1 dir ==>Direction control. When high, the signal propagates from A to B. When low, the signal DIR 1 A2 I
propagates from B to A. (datasheet)

Comment: it looks like pin 1 is soldered to the ground plane

Comment: The LC245A has 8 ports per chip, so if you have a group of 8 buttons not functioning that may point to one of the chips being defective in some way.